# Ошибка страницы в ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Здравствуйте. Есть проблема с загрузкой страницы в проекте ASP.NET. На форме проекта есть элемент chart на котором расположена диаграмма. Если я просто открою форму то я её вижу нормально но когда в запущенном проекте пытаюсь зайти на неё вылетает вот такая вот ошибка

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Invalid temp directory in chart handler configuration [c:\TempImageFiles\].'
```

В чём может быть проблема? Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Проблема в том, что у вас в настройках обработчика `chart` указана неверная временная директория `c:\TempImageFiles\`. И ASP.NET не может её найти.

Comment: @Dmitry то есть я должен указать директорию где распологается сам chart?

Comment: Думаю, в настройках надо указать существующую на файловой системе директорию, к которой есть доступ у пользователя, от имени которого запускается приложение

Comment: @Dmitry спасибо большое. Помогло. В web.config задал другой путь, плюс потребовалось в ручную создать эту самую директорию. И всё заработало. Если не сложно оформите пожалуйста свой комментарий как ответ что бы я мог закрыть тему. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Да не за что. Не сложно, напишу ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у вас в настройках обработчика *chart* указана неверная временная директория `c:\TempImageFiles`. И ASP.NET не может её найти.

Чтобы решить эту проблему, в настройках надо указать существующую на файловой системе директорию, к которой есть доступ у пользователя, от имени которого запускается приложение.